# Regarding a false claim about extrema

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, maxima-minima

Consider the following false claim:

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. A point $x_0\in(a,b)$ is called a **local maximum point** iff there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x_0$ such that $\forall x\in N\backslash x_0\ f(x)<f(x_0)$ (note the $<$ sign). Then, a global maximum point $x\in[a,b]$ is either a local maximum point or one of $\{a,b\}$.

This claim is easily falsified by the following piecewise function, which is constant in $[1,2]$:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\in [0,1]\\1&x\in [1,2]\\3-x&x\in [2,3]\end{cases}$$

In this case the global maximum is achieved anywhere in $[1,2]$, but none of these points satisfy the definition of "local maximum point" because of the $<$ sign in the definition instead of $\le$.

**Question**: is there a counterexample that is constant on no intervals?

Remark and motivation: apparently, the above false result is stated in multiple Chinese junior high school textbooks. However, for some reason, the problem went unfixed -- the *gaokao* problems on differentiation usually do not involve functions constant on some interval!

Comment: Your definition means that the function has a strict maximum at the point $x_0.$ The function does not need to admit strict extremal points.

Comment: Please clarify: Are you looking for a function which is not constant on any interval and has (at least) *one* global maximum which is not a strict local maximum, or are you looking for a function which is not constant on any interval and *every* global maximum is not a strict local maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is afforded by

$$
f(x)=x^2\left(\sin\frac1x-1\right)
$$

on any interval with $0$ in its interior. This function is not constant on any interval; it’s continuous and non-positive and vanishes at infinitely many points in every neighbourhood of $0$; so $0$ is a global maximum but not a strict local maximum.

You didn’t give a definition of a global maximum, but it seems to be implied in your example that a global maximum is not defined as a strict global maximum, whereas a local maximum is defined as a strict local maximum; that seems slightly inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks! The inconsistency comes from how the textbooks mentioned state the result.